# Pointer to class member

Tags: c++

Is there a way to obtain pointer to class member variable the same way as pointer to class member function inside static member function as code below shows?:

```
uint16_t (Packet::*fncPtr)() = &Packet::someFnc; // get member function pointer
Packet p = Packet(); // instantiate class
(p.*fncPtr)(); // call member function
```

One solution might be implementation of getters and usage of pointers to 
 getter functions.
I don't need it, I'm just curious.

Random example:

```
auto packet = Packet();
?someT? memberVariablePtr;    
if(strategy == Strategy::printSrcMac){
    memberVariablePtr = // get pointer to packet.macSrc variable
} else if(strategy == Strategy::printDstMac){
    memberVariablePtr = // get pointer to packet.macDst variable
}

print(memberVariablePtr)
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve. Can you show some (imaginary, non-working) code and explain what it should do?

Comment: I think he is trying to call a member function of `Packet` using `p` but provided code doesn't do justice.

Comment: Voted to close as unclear.

Comment: My guess is that he's actually trying to get a pointer to a member variable, the same way a pointer to a member function can be obtained...

Comment: @Quentin Question now includes some example.

Comment: @eran you are right

Comment: Closed, hence an answer as a comment: try ... `using namespace std::placeholders;
    int srcOrDst = 2;
    auto refToSrcOrDst = srcOrDst==1 ? std::bind(&Packet::macSrc, _1) : std::bind(&Packet::macDst, _1);
    Packet foo;
    std::cout << refToSrcOrDst(foo) << '\n';`

Comment: Get the offset (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstddef/offsetof/) to the variable & increment the pointer to the object by that amount.  You'll have to do some casting magic afterwards though

Comment: @SamoPoláček http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9eccbc5b7b8a3628, possible ways you can do this.

Comment: You obtain and use it in exactly the same way – `int Packet::* m = &Packet::member; print(packet.*m);`.

Comment: None of solutions above works in static member function. I'm wondering why it's possible to get reference to (not static) member function inside static member function but at the same time it's not possible to get reference to (not static) member variable inside the same static member function.

Comment: Where in your question did you mention `static member` function?

Comment: @SamerTufail I accidentally removed it during edit.

Comment: You might want to see [this article](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members).

Answer (score 2):

You can create pointers to members in the exact same way as you create pointers to member functions:

```
auto packet = Packet();
MacAddr Packet::*memberVariablePtr = nullptr;

if(strategy == Strategy::printSrcMac) {
    memberVariablePtr = &Packet::macSrc;
} else if(strategy == Strategy::printDstMac) {
    memberVariablePtr = &Packet::macDst;
}

print(memberVariablePtr);
```

This supposes that the type of `Packet::macSrc` and `Packet::macDst` is `MacAddr`.
You can also factorize it:

```
auto packet = Packet();
MacAddr Packet::*memberVariablePtr
    = strategy == Strategy::printSrcMac ? &Packet::macSrc
    : strategy == Strategy::printDstMac ? &Packet::macDst
    : nullptr;

print(memberVariablePtr);
```

Comment: How is the `memberVariablePtr` used in relation to the created object instance `packet` in order to obtain the value from the object `packet`? Currently it seems to me the members you point to are static...

Comment: @anddero Same thing as member functions again, `(packet.*memberVariablePtr)`.